# Link header and first page header in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

Is there a way in Word 2010 to link the header and the first page header so that all pages have the same header and when the first page header is changed, it is automatically changed on all other pages?

(I understand that I could turn off having a different first page, but that can't be done in this particular case because there is a different footer on the first page than the other pages.)

Answer (score 0):

No not as such, the first page header and footers are completely separate from the primary and even header footers.

The only you could link the first page header to other pages would be to create a new section on every page and set different first page header footer and then link the the header to the previous section. This would need to be repeated for every further page.